# How to view 1 Line in a .txt Document, then display the next line the next day with PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to add a different Coupon Code on my Site every day. Doing this manually seems to take up a lot of unnecessary time. Is there any  way i could just paste 365 Codes into a .txt File and display 1 line per day?

Comment: Yes, you can insert coupons via cron into DB.

Comment: @nice_dev that just wasn't the question was it?

Comment: Of course not, but DB is a better choice than a txt file.

Comment: @nice_dev how would that code look like? So it prints 1 code and then pri9nts the code of the next id the next day?

Comment: Yes that could be one way or you could set one day expiry dates against each coupon and query from the DB only those coupons which are valid for the current day.

Comment: @nice_dev can iprint the same code a year later with your approach or would that make the code unuseable forever after 1 use?

Comment: Once the coupon code expires, it wouldn't be reusable. It would be better to do it this way rather than having guessable coupon codes for the end user on a yearly basis.

Comment: @nice_dev so do you maybe have a code example on how to actually do this?

Comment: Yes, I can share an abstract idea but can you let me know some coupon code examples for me to grasp it's feel and look?

Comment: @nice_dev you can use CUP1 and CUP2 as examples for Coupon Codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `date()` to get the current day of the year and then `file()` to read the complete file as array.

```
<?php

// Fill the tmp file
define('CouponCodeFile', 'file.txt');

file_put_contents(CouponCodeFile, '');
for ($i=1; $i <= 365 ; $i++) { 
    file_put_contents(CouponCodeFile, sprintf("Coupon_Code_Day_%s\n", $i), FILE_APPEND);
}

// Read Coupon Code from file 
$curr_day = date('z');
$CouponCodeFileLines = file(CouponCodeFile);
printf("Your Coupon Code for the day %d is: %s\n", $curr_day+1, $CouponCodeFileLines[$curr_day]);

?>
```

Comment: will date() use the server time?

Comment: yes, its an unix-timestamp so it will be UTC-based

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table called `coupons` like so

```
create table coupons(
    id int primary key not null auto_increment,
    coupon_name varchar(255),
    start_date timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    end_date timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    created_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

**Cron Script:**

You can create a script like below to run on 1<sup>st</sup> day of every year:

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$days = getDaysInTheYear(date('Y'));
$coupons = [];

$day = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d',date('Y'). '-01-01');

for($i = 1; $i <= $days; ++$i){
    $coupons[] = [
        getRandomChars(4) . '_CUP' . $i,
        $day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        $day->format('Y-m-d'). ' 23:59:59',
        date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    ];

    $day = $day->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}

function getRandomChars($len){
    $chars = range('A', 'Z');
    shuffle($chars);
    $str = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i){
        $str .= $chars[rand(0, count($chars) - 1)];
    }
    
    return $str;
}

function getDaysInTheYear($year){
    return $year % 100 == 0 && $year % 400 == 0 || 
           $year % 100 != 0 && $year % 4 == 0 ? 366 : 365;
}


print_r($coupons);

/*

 mysqli DB connections etc

*/
// bulk insert all coupons at once

$coupons = array_map(fn($v) => "'".implode("','",$v). "'", $coupons);
try{
    if($conn->query("insert into coupons(coupon_name, start_date, end_date, created_at) values(". implode("),(", $coupons). ")") === false){
        throw new \Exception("Couldn't insert coupons: ". $conn->error);
    }
}catch(\Exception $e){
    // your code
}finally{
    $conn->close();
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/1a1d5)

Cron syntax to setup on your server would be like so:

```
0 0 1 1 *
```

[**Cron mnemonic**](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_1_*)

**Fetching coupons:**

While fetching valid coupons, it could be as simple as:

```
<?php

$result = $conn->query("select * from coupons where start_date >= 'your_start_date' and end_date <= 'your_end_date');

// rest of your code
```